# Selectively replace substring

Tags: java, string, replace

```
String str = "hdfCity1kdCity12fsd".
```

I want to replace only `City1` with `Goa` without replacing `City1` sequence in `City1X` in above String.

I tried using replace function.

```
str = str.replace("City1", "Goa")
```

but the result is

```
str = "hdfGoakdGoa2fsd"
```

how to do this selective replace? to get this desired result

```
str = "hdfGoakdCity12fsd";//solution: str.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)City1(?!\\d)", "Goa");
```

## sorry for making my case not clear

Thanks @TiiJ7

Comment: Please edit & add a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: This doesn't look like javascript? String str = 'some text' is not valid

Comment: @Roy -- Allow OP to set language. Also, can't be javascript as that would provide correct result.

Comment: This looks like Java.

Comment: thanks for your interest in this, the exact case is similar to like this "City1****City12" where * is any thing except Int charector and I'm looking for generic code like replacing CityX(where), not just City1 and City12. #stars added before City1 and after City2 are not visible after i submitted my comment

Comment: @TiiJ7 Not working, result is same as initial string.

Comment: Yes, in that case your situation is slightly different from the one I linked. You'll need something like `str.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)City1(?!\\d)", "Goa")`. You need to check if it works for all your cases, though. ([test online](https://regex101.com/r/WxqNbr/2) if you want)

Comment: @TiiJ7 It's working, big load of thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replaceFirst() or replaceAll() method, but if you want to replace in the middle, you can find the occurrence you are looking for (one example here: [Occurrences of substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string))

Use the index returned to make 2 substrings: the first part remain unchanged and, in the second part, the first occurrence must be replaced (replaceFirst())

Last: join the two substrings.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking like this: ill find the occurences, for each occurence ill check for next character type, if it is integer ill replace the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you could use `replaceFirst()`. This will only replace the first occurence of your matched String:

```
String str = "City1 is beautiful than City12";
str = str.replaceFirst("City1", "Goa");
System.out.println(str);
```

Will output:

```
Goa is beautiful than City12
```

Other than that you could use a more sophisticated regex to match your exact case, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30183873/6436977).

Comment: What if the string is  "City12 is beautiful than City1"?

Comment: In this case OP would need a regex, I linked the answer below mine.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you might be right though if that's what OP intended this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: That is what I voted for.

Comment: thanks for your interest in this, the exact case is similar to like this "***City1****City12***" where * is any thing except Int charector and I'm looking for generic code like replacing CityX(where), not just City1 and City12.
#stars added before City1 and after City2 are not visible after i submitted my comment

Comment: If your statement is *always* formulated like this and you *always* want to replace the first city name, `replaceFirst()` is your best option.

Comment: @Slowdeath451 My solution should still work after your edit. The contents before and after the matched String have no impact on the result.

Comment: yes, replaceFirst() works fine for the case mentioned, but If order gets changed, the code function wont serve purpose. In my actual code i dont have any control how strings is ordered.

Comment: Then you will have to do an exact match, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183807/java-string-replace-exact-word/30183873#30183873

Comment: I'm thinking like this, I'll find the occurrences of City1 and for every occurrence ill check for the character at next index, if the character is not integer. I'll replace the occurrence with 'Goa'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method `replaceFirst(regex, replacement)` :

```
 String str = "City1 is beautiful than City12";
 System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("City1", "Goa")); // Goa is beautiful than City12
```

Comment: What if the string is "City12 is beautiful than City1"?

Comment: my code wont solve this ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about the first part, you could also use the substring method.
Example:

```
String str = "City1 is beautiful than City12";
str = "Goa" + str.substring(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that City1 will not any characters around except whitespace you can use:

```
String str = "City1 is beautiful than than City12";
str = str.replace("City1 ", "Goa ");
System.out.println(str);
```

same as yours but additional space at the end of the replacing and new string

Comment: This is exactly what OP already tried.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Probably you didn't read my answer carefully :) I have one more extra spaces after replacing strings

Comment: Ok I missed that but it doesn’t change much, what about “1City1 “ for instance? You are ignoring that it is a specific word that should be replaced.