# Replace words in Java string

Tags: java

I have a String that looks like this:

```
downloadUrl = "https://example.com/uploads/images/quotes/hi/webp/dard-status-shayari-68854.webp";
```

It is basically a URL address. I'm looking to replace `webp` with `jpg` and `.webp` with `.jpeg`

I need output like the below:

```
https://example.com/uploads/images/quotes/hi/jpg/dard-status-shayari-68854.jpeg
```

I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183807/java-string-replace-exact-word) but it's not working for me.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you have tried?

Comment: can you share what you've tried and why it failed?

Comment: what issue are you facing by using https://stackoverflow.com/a/30183873/11670453?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
String result = source.replaceFirst("\\.webp$",".jpeg").replace("webp","jpg");
```

`replaceFirst()` will replace the extention, then `replace()` will replace the rest...